# How to set my Name in smack?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I can use connection.getRoster(),getName to get roster names of contact.
But how to **set** the name of current authenticated account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log in with a different account? :)

Seriously, your account name is tied to your authentication, and there's no way to force the other side to use a particular nickname for you, but if both sides implement [XEP-172](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0172.html), you can send a hint to the other side when you subscribe:

```
<presence from='narrator@moby-dick.lit' to='starbuck@moby-dick.lit' type='subscribe'>
  <nick xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'>Ishmael</nick>
</presence>
```