# How to change your own name using Smack?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

You can use `RosterEntry` to get the name of your contacts. But how I change my **own** name and it appears to my contacts when they do

```
RosterEntry entry = roster.getEntries("myuser");
entry.getName(); // It needs to show my updated name
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this Q/A provide an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/q/4807796/105224

Comment: So I change my name is impossible without XEP-172?

Comment: Do you want to change your account name or your real name?

Comment: I want to change the real name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the other users haven't set a custom nickname for you, I *think* Spark will display your first and last name, which you may be able to change with:

```
VCard me = new VCard();
me.load(conn); // load own VCard
me.setFirstName("John");
me.setLastName("Doe");
me.save(conn);
```

Comment: I put **ProviderManager.getInstance().addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());** before that above code and it is working now!